# Question about replace command

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

I want to replace the common part in the equation by different value.
Here is my equation

```
    -(3/(2*θ)) - (1/2)*Sqrt[9/θ^2 - (2*(-18 + θ))/(3*θ^2) + (324 - 252*θ - 23*θ^2)/
      (3*θ^2*(-5832 + 6804*θ - 702*θ^2 + 73*θ^3 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[-324*θ^3 + 306*θ^4 + 17*θ^5 + θ^6])^(1/3)) + 
     (-5832 + 6804*θ - 702*θ^2 + 73*θ^3 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[-324*θ^3 + 306*θ^4 + 17*θ^5 + θ^6])^(1/3)/(3*θ^2)] + 
  (1/2)*Sqrt[18/θ^2 - (4*(-18 + θ))/(3*θ^2) - (324 - 252*θ - 23*θ^2)/
      (3*θ^2*(-5832 + 6804*θ - 702*θ^2 + 73*θ^3 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[-324*θ^3 + 306*θ^4 + 17*θ^5 + θ^6])^(1/3)) - 
     (-5832 + 6804*θ - 702*θ^2 + 73*θ^3 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[-324*θ^3 + 306*θ^4 + 17*θ^5 + θ^6])^(1/3)/(3*θ^2) - 
     (-(216/θ^3) + (24*(-18 + θ))/θ^3 - 96/θ^2)/(4*Sqrt[9/θ^2 - (2*(-18 + θ))/(3*θ^2) + (324 - 252*θ - 23*θ^2)/
          (3*θ^2*(-5832 + 6804*θ - 702*θ^2 + 73*θ^3 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[-324*θ^3 + 306*θ^4 + 17*θ^5 + θ^6])^(1/3)) + 
         (1/(3*θ^2))*(-5832 + 6804*θ - 702*θ^2 + 73*θ^3 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[-324*θ^3 + 306*θ^4 + 17*θ^5 + θ^6])^(1/3)])]
```

which looks too complicate. However, this include the common part,

```
(-5832 + 6804*θ - 702*θ^2 + 73*θ^3
    + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[-324*θ^3 + 306*θ^4 + 17*θ^5 + θ^6])^(1/3)
```

Thus, I replace this part by A using the command

```
% /. (-5832 + 6804*θ - 702*θ^2 + 73*θ^3
         + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[-324*θ^3 + 306*θ^4 + 17*θ^5 + θ^6])^(1/3) -> A
```

However, the output shows that not all common parts are changed into A.
I get the output,

```
-(3/(2*θ)) - (1/2)*Sqrt[9/θ^2 + A/(3*θ^2) - (2*(-18 + θ))/(3*θ^2) + (324 - 252*θ - 23*θ^2)/
      (3*θ^2*(-5832 + 6804*θ - 702*θ^2 + 73*θ^3 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[-324*θ^3 + 306*θ^4 + 17*θ^5 + θ^6])^(1/3))] + 
  (1/2)*Sqrt[18/θ^2 - A/(3*θ^2) - (4*(-18 + θ))/(3*θ^2) - (324 - 252*θ - 23*θ^2)/
      (3*θ^2*(-5832 + 6804*θ - 702*θ^2 + 73*θ^3 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[-324*θ^3 + 306*θ^4 + 17*θ^5 + θ^6])^(1/3)) - 
     (-(216/θ^3) + (24*(-18 + θ))/θ^3 - 96/θ^2)/(4*Sqrt[9/θ^2 + A/(3*θ^2) - (2*(-18 + θ))/(3*θ^2) + (324 - 252*θ - 23*θ^2)/
          (3*θ^2*(-5832 + 6804*θ - 702*θ^2 + 73*θ^3 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[-324*θ^3 + 306*θ^4 + 17*θ^5 + θ^6])^(1/3))])]
```

which still has the common part,

```
(-5832 + 6804*θ - 702*θ^2 + 73*θ^3 + 54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[-324*θ^3 + 306*θ^4 + 17*θ^5 + θ^6])^(1/3)
```

How can I chance all these common parts at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
% /. {(-5832 + 6804*θ - 702*θ^2 + 73*θ^3 + 
        54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[-324*θ^3 + 306*θ^4 + 
        17*θ^5 + θ^6])^(1/3) -> A, 
      (-5832 + 6804*θ - 702*θ^2 + 73*θ^3 + 
        54*Sqrt[6]*Sqrt[-324*θ^3 + 306*θ^4 + 
        17*θ^5 + θ^6])^(-1/3) -> 1/A}
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that

```
1/x^1/3 // FullForm
(* Times[Rational[1, 3], Power[x, -1]] *)
```

That is, powers in denominators are automatically parsed as *negative* powers. So as noted in [Cesareo's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/190091/29734) answer, you have to find the negative powers as well. I would do the following to help automate this process.

First inspect your expression for sub-expressions that might be the same:

```
Cases[expr, (_)^(-1/3) | (_)^(1/3), Infinity] // DeleteDuplicates
(* {1/(-5832 + 6804 θ - 702 θ^2 + 73 θ^3
         + 54 Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-324 θ^3 + 306 θ^4 + 17 θ^5 + θ^6])^(1/3),
    (-5832 + 6804 θ - 702 θ^2 + 73 θ^3
         + 54 Sqrt[6] Sqrt[-324 θ^3 + 306 θ^4 + 17 θ^5 + θ^6])^(1/3)} *)
```

(Here, `expr` is your long expression.) By inspecting just these parts, we can see that every sub-expression of the form $(\textrm{something})^{1/3}$ is the same. So, we can do a much simpler replacement rule that requires much less typing:

```
expr /. {a_^(1/3) -> A, a_^(-1/3) -> 1/A}
```